# Visual Studio 6 SVN plugin

Tags: svn, plugins, version-control, visual-studio-6

We currently use AnkhSvn with Visual Studio 2008 but have one solution that is still coded in Visual Studio 6.

Are there any SVN plugins that operate with such an old IDE?

Looking to move away from SourceSafe (shudder) and amalgamate our source control but would prefer to have a tool within the IDE rather than using tortoise SVN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there any SVN plugins that operate with such an old IDE?

The [Agent SVN](http://zeusedit.com/agent/) plug-in works with *Visual C++ 6.0* and *Visual Studio 2008*.

The setup for both of these IDEs is described in the help file.

Answer (score 1):

Pushok's CVS SCC proxy plug-in is supposed to work with any version that supports SCC and that should include VS 6. It can be found here: http://www.pushok.com/soft_svn.php

Edit: Though when I used pushok's plugin I found that it made VS a little flaky, but that was about 5-6 years ago and I think that was the CVS one so might be a completely different matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this website http://www.wndtabs.com/

There are tools here for VS6/ Visual Studio 6/ Dev Studio 6 WndTabs does allow you to access SVN.

The comment by the original developer is a little heart breaking as he obviously did put a lot of effort and passion into creating these tools. I really wish I know about them used then back in the day when VS6 was a main staple and not the legacy issue it is for many developers who are stuck using it until work is migrated.

The other tool is visual assist at www.wholetomato.com is the best tool for VS6 but you have to pay for it

If anyone has any thoughts just add them in as well